# Adding and removing views

Tags: android

Good day

I have a ViewGroup with 5 views.  When added, the views are obviously indexed from 0 to 4.

---

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

---

I am detecting horizontal slide events, and I want to do this:
When I slide from view index 2 to view index 3, I want to remove view index 0 and add a new view at the end of the group.
When I slide from view index 2 to view index 1, I want to remove view index 4 and add a new view at index 0.

All the time I need 5 views, but I want to add and remove them as I move.

Can anyone give me an advice to do this (without lag preferable).

Note: If anyone knows a good component (no ViewFlipper) to slide to the sides giving the idea that the views are infinite, but keeping the drag/slide effect we find in the launcher, please let me know.

Comment: I am using RealViewSwitcher (http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html) to use this, but that class switches a finite number of views.  I am using the class' listener to try to add and remove views when switching, but it's laggy and I don't know how to add new views at the left (index 0) to make it look infinite.

Comment: Some code would be nice so we can play around with it, too.

Comment: What I want to do is exactly as this app can do when moving through months (http://www.appbrain.com/app/jorte/jp.co.johospace.jorte).